# How can I make an ajax request after fetch post?

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, fetch

I have a fetch post and after I want to make an ajax request:

```
$(document).on('change', '.item-select', function() {
     fetch(`/row/${entity}/${relation}/${optionValue}`,{
        method: 'POST'
     })
    $.ajax({
        url:'{{ path('select', { 'slug': page.slug, 'id': id, 'parent': parent   }) }}',
        success : function (data) {
          $(".output").html(data.output);
        }
      });
});
```

The problem is, that this seems not to work propery. Is it possible to tell the ajax request to make sure, not to start before the fetch post is completed?

Comment: Why would you mix that? Why using post for a get request?

Comment: WHY are you using fetch and then $.ajax?  Why not  $.ajax $.ajax or fetch.then  fetch???

Comment: Both fetch and ajax are async `fetch(...).then( () => { $.ajax(...) } );`

Comment: @mplungjan Is this better?

Comment: @Jarla is what better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it in the `.then()` callback for the promise returned by `fetch()`:

```
fetch(`/row/${entity}/${relation}/${optionValue}`,{
    method: 'POST'
}).then(function () {
    $.ajax({
      //...
    });
});
```

Fetch is an asynchronuos AJAX operation just like jQuery's `$.ajax()`, follow-up operations would happen in the promise's callbacks.  (Though it's very strange that you're using both, normally one would either use jQuery or not use jQuery.  But that's immaterial to the problem I suppose.)